# Not Able to Skip Adding CSS Rule to First li Element Using not(first)

Tags: css

Can you please take a look at this demo and let me know why I am not able to not add the css rule to the first item using the not option?

```css
li:not(first) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2
    <ul>
      <li>Item 2-1</li>
      <li>Item 2-2</li>
      <li>Item 2-3</li>
      <li>Item 2-4</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably meant `:not(:first-child)` (there is no CSS `first`). There is [`:first`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first) but that's for printing:

> The `:first` @page CSS pseudo-class describes the styling of the first
>   page when printing a document.

```css
li:not(:first-child){  color:red;  }
```

```html
<ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2
                <ul>
                    <li>Item 2-1</li>
                    <li>Item 2-2</li>
                    <li>Item 2-3</li>
                    <li>Item 2-4</li>
                </ul>
         </li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

You could also do `li:not(:first-of-type)`:

```css
li:not(:first-of-type){  color:red;  }
```

```html
<ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2
                <ul>
                    <li>Item 2-1</li>
                    <li>Item 2-2</li>
                    <li>Item 2-3</li>
                    <li>Item 2-4</li>
                </ul>
         </li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Or `li:not(:nth-child(1))`:

```css
li:not(:nth-child(1)){  color:red;  }
```

```html
<ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2
                <ul>
                    <li>Item 2-1</li>
                    <li>Item 2-2</li>
                    <li>Item 2-3</li>
                    <li>Item 2-4</li>
                </ul>
         </li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Or `li:not(:nth-of-type(1))`:

```css
li:not(:nth-of-type(1)){  color:red;  }
```

```html
<ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2
                <ul>
                    <li>Item 2-1</li>
                    <li>Item 2-2</li>
                    <li>Item 2-3</li>
                    <li>Item 2-4</li>
                </ul>
         </li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

By the way, if you're wondering why the inner list doesnt have its first element's color changed it because color is an inherited property.

Answer (score 2):

You got the syntax wrong

```
 li:not(:first-child)
```